# Python code displays Error 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: python, apache, cgi, cpanel

1) A python code works properly in local console.
2) I transfer this code via ftp to the server, run it in web and it doesn't work displaying Internal Server Error.
3) I open and edit this code directly from the server via cpanel and save it without any change, not even an indentation change. Then the code starts working properly in the web.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def main():
    print "hello"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
    main()
```

Server log: End of script output before headers: x.py

htcaccess:

```
Options +ExecCGI
Options -Indexes
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
AddHandler py-bin .py
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

Can someone explain what may be wrong with the server?

Comment: Error 500??? What do you mean exactly? This is the only code you have? Both of them work on my machine. You are obviously leaving something out...

Comment: Well, what's the real error on the server? 500 is "Internal Server Error," so something isn't working on the server, and it could be one of a million things. Consider looking into how to write a [mcve], since anyone can run both of these in an interpreter and they'll work fine.

Comment: What's in the error log of the server?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `#!/usr/bin/python` by `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/local/env python`

Or maybe your script needs some permissions

[image: How to run Python scripts]